# How can i make a welcome page with a file which has .html extension

Tags: spring

Hello i am new to spring, 
I am trying to create a welcome file called index.html 
I put my index.html file under webapp folder. My web xml file is

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

 <display-name>Spring4MVCHelloWorldDemo Web Application</display-name>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>



</web-app>
```

And my spring-servlet.xml file is

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.websystique.springmvc" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

When i change index.html to index.jsp and create an index.jsp file it works fine. My question is can`t i make welcome page with html extension ? If i can what is my mistake ? thanks

```
<welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've configured the `InternalResourceViewResolver` to search files with `.jsp` suffix. In this case, Spring won't match `index.html`.

You can replace the `suffix` value with `.html` if you need to match files under `/WEB-INF/views/{viewName}.html`